# Hide whiskers and outliers in box plot plotly express and adjust color tone python

Tags: python, plotly

Is it possible to remove the whiskers and outliers in plotly express box plot in python ? My code looks like below: Also, is there a way, I can give 2 sets of colors ? for example I have 3 labels and each label has 2 categories.
I wanted to have same color for each label but the color tone alone, I wanted to reduce for each category as well.

```
fig = px.box(all_services, x="xvalue", y="yvalue", color="label",
            title="title")
fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="inclusive",boxpoints=False)
```